# Kafka Streams: Send an event for every 50 records of a particular field in a topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic where I receive the following events from multiple nodes:

```
{ eventName : "script_execution_complete", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostA" } 
{ eventName : "script_execution_complete", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostB" }
{ eventName : "script_execution_complete", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostC" }
{ eventName : "script_execution_complete", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostA" }
{ eventName : "script_execution_complete", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostB" }
{ eventName : "script_execution_complete", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostC" }
```

I want to send a special event to another for every 50 occurrences of the above event for each host. For example, For every 50th/100th/150th occurrence of the "script_execution_complete" event for the "hostA", I want to send the following event to another topic from the streams application.

```
{ eventName : "grid_node_restart", eventTime : "<time_in_iso_format>", hostname : "hostA" }
```

How do I do this in Kafka Streams? I cannot define a particular Window with a time frame as we don't know how long will it take to receive the 50th event (or 100th/150th event) for a given node.

Will a simple count() aggregation work after grouping them by hostnames? Is this scalable? My attempt to solve this is following:

```
streamsBuilder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), gridJobEventSerde,
                new AutomationEventTimestampExtractor(), null))
                .filter((key, value) ->
                        value.getEventName().equals("script_execution_complete"))
                .flatMap((key, value) -> {
                    String hostname = value.getPayload().getHostname();
                    if(hostname != null){
                        hostname = hostname.trim().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                    }
                    List<KeyValue<String, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

                    result.add(new KeyValue<>(hostname, 1));
                    return result;
                })
                .groupByKey()
                .count()
                .toStream()
                .filter((key, value) -> value % 50 == 0)
                .flatMap((hostname, value) -> {
                    int errorCount = Math.toIntExact(value);
                    GridClusterEventPayload payload = new GridClusterEventPayload();
                    payload.setHostname(hostname);
                    GridClusterEvent gridClusterEvent = new GridClusterEvent();
                    gridClusterEvent.setEventName("grid_node_restart");
                    gridClusterEvent.setEventTime(new Date());
                    gridClusterEvent.setPayload(payload);
                    List<KeyValue<String, GridClusterEvent>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    result.add(new KeyValue<>(hostname, gridClusterEvent));
                    return result;
                })
                .to("grid_cluster", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), gridClusterEventSerdes));
```

The count of events will easily go very high very fast. I feel the above solution is not a scalable one as more and more events would be processed and the count would increased.

I want to reset the "count" of these events after every 50th event. Is this possible by defining a window without specifying time frames?  Is there a better way to implement this?

EDIT:
Even if a time window needs to specified, How can I send the restart event when either the 50th event has occured OR when the time window is expired? In the later case, even though the 50th event has not occurred, I would like to send the restart event after a window is expired and the count should reset in the next window.

Comment: To fix the values going above 50, you would need to replace `.count()` with `.reduce` and implement your own aggregation functions. Also, depending on how high the value can go, you might want to use `Long` rather than `Integer`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks, I will try that. We have a good cleanup and retention policy in the cluster (on both input and output topics for this builder). I know long datatype will handle the event count value but somehow it doesn't feel right to maintain the ever-increasing count value for this use-case. Also, is there anyway we can define a custom tumbling window based on the count of events occurred in the topic? The window should reset after every 50th event of a particular node(denoted by the hostname field).

Comment: That would need to be done with session windows, but I dont think you can define a "size" for them. At least, not via DSL methods.

Comment: I think the following works now. 
`.groupByKey().reduce((value1, value2) -> (value1 + value2) % 50L).toStream().filter((key, value) -> value == 0)`
This should ensure the aggregate value never crosses, 50. Thanks!

Comment: Another solution, depending on what you need, would be to give an initializer of an arraylist, then add each value to the list in the combiner, making sure it never grows beyond 50 items. Then you can `mapValues(v -> v.size())` if you wanted the size of the grouping

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need a `flatmap` as your list only has one item. Just `map` and `return new KeyValue<>(hostname, 1)` or `new KeyValue<>(hostname, gridClusterEvent)`